# Redirect powershell in batch file works to file but not to null

Tags: powershell, batch-file

The following line of code (in a 'Administrator' cmd window on Windows 10) outputs the title of some open windows to the me.txt file, and not to the screen:

```
POWERSHELL "Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ''} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle" 1>C:\me.txt
```

But the following line outputs to the screen, even though I say don't:

```
POWERSHELL "Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ''} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle" 1>NUL
```

Any ideas?

And I know that there is no point to the command if I am not interested in the result...

[Update] The reason for doing this is because the first time the line is run, it takes almost a second longer than subsequent times, so I wanted to run it once up front to make subsequent times more consistent. In those subsequent runs I do look at the results :-)

Comment: working as expected, here in win 8 enterprise.

Comment: thanks, it worked ok in XP too :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this produce the expect result? Apologies cannot test as no admin

```
POWERSHELL "Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ''} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle | Out-Null"
```

Comment: Yay! that seems to work. Presumably it won't optimise things and not do anything at all? Sounds a bit advanced for PowerShell?

Comment: Just checked, it doesn't optimise as far as I can tell, thanks gmsoulman